# incremental select using id from SQLite in Twisted

Tags: sqlite, twisted

I am trying to select data from a table in SQLite one row ONLY at a time for each call to the function, and I want the row to increment on each call (self.count is initialized elsewhere and 'line' is irrelevant here) I am using an adbapi connection pool in Twisted to connect to the DB. Here is the code I have tried:

```
def queryBTData4(self,line):
    self.count=self.count+1
    uuId=self.count
    query="SELECT co2_data, patient_Id FROM btdata4 WHERE uid=:uid",{"uid": uuId}          
    d = self.dbpool.runQuery(query)
    return d
```

This code works if I just set uid=1 or any other number in the DB (I used autoincrement for uid when I created the DB) but when I try to assign a value to uid (i.e. self.count via uuId) it reports that the operator has to be string or unicode.(I have tried both but it does not seem to help) However, I know that the query statement above works just fine in a previous program when I use a cursor and the execute command but I cannot see why it does not work here. I have tried all sorts of combinations and searched for a solution but have not found anything yet that works.(I have also tried the statement with brackets and other forms)

Thanks for any help or advice.

Here is the entire code:

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
from twisted.protocols import basic
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
import sqlite3, time


class ServerProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('biomed2.db',check_same_thread=False)
        self.dbpool =  adbapi.ConnectionPool("sqlite3" , 'biomed2.db',  check_same_thread=False)


    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendLine("conn made")
        factory = protocol.ClientFactory()
        factory.protocol = ClientProtocol
        factory.originator = self
        reactor.connectTCP('localhost', 1234, factory)

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        self._received = line
        self.insertBTData4(self._received)
        self.sendLine("line recvd") 

    def forwardLine(self, recipient):
        recipient.sendLine(self._received)      


    def insertBTData4(self,data):
        print "data in insert is",data
        chx=data
        PID=2
        device_ID=5
        query="INSERT INTO btdata4(co2_data,patient_Id, sensor_Id) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')" % (chx, PID, device_ID) 
        dF = self.dbpool.runQuery(query)
        return dF

class ClientProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('biomed2.db',check_same_thread=False)
        self.dbpool =  adbapi.ConnectionPool("sqlite3" , 'biomed2.db',  check_same_thread=False)
        self.count=0


    def connectionMade(self):
        print "server-client made connection with client"
        self.factory.originator.forwardLine(self)
        #self.transport.loseConnection()


    def lineReceived(self, line):
        d=self.queryBTData4(self)
        d.addCallbacks(self.sendData,self.printError )


    def queryBTData4(self,line):
        self.count=self.count+1
        query=("SELECT co2_data, patient_Id FROM btdata4 WHERE uid=:uid",{"uid": uuId})          
        dF = self.dbpool.runQuery(query)
        return dF

    def sendData(self,line):
        data=str(line)
        self.sendLine(data) 

    def printError(self,error):
        print "Got Error: %r" % error
        error.printTraceback()


def main():
    factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = ServerProtocol
    reactor.listenTCP(4321, factory)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The DB is created in another program, thus:

```
import sqlite3, time, string
conn = sqlite3.connect('biomed2.db')

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE btdata4
             (uid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, co2_data integer, patient_Id integer, sensor_Id   integer)''')
```

The main program takes data into the server socket and inserts into DB. On the client socket side, data is removed from the DB one line at a time and sent to an external server. The program also has the ability to send data from the server side to the client side if required but I am not doing so here at the moment.

In queryBTData(), every time the function is called the count increments and I assign that value to uuId, which I then pass to the query. I have had this query statement working in a program where I do not use the adbapi but it does not seem to work here. I hope this is clear enough but if not please let me know and I will try again.

EDIT:

I have modified the program to take one row from the DB at a time (see queryBTData() below) but have come across another problem.

```
def queryBTData4(self,line):
    self.count=self.count+1
    xuId= self.count
    #xuId=10
    return self.dbpool.runQuery("SELECT co2_data FROM btdata4 WHERE uid = ?",xuId)
    #return self.dbpool.runQuery("SELECT co2_data FROM btdata4 WHERE uid = 10")
```

When the count gets to 10 I get an error (which I will post below) which states that: "Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied"

I have tried setting xuId to 10 (see commented out line xuId=10) but I still get the same error. However, if I switch the return statements (to commented out return) I do indeed get correct row with no error. I have tried converting xuId to unicode but that makes no difference, I still get the same error. Basically, if I I set uid in the return statement to 10 or more (commented out return) it works, but if I set uid to xuId (i.e. uid=?,xuId) in the first return, it only works when xuId is below 10. The API documentation, as far as I can tell, gives no clue as to why this occurs.(I have also disabled the insert into DB to eliminate this and checked the SQLite3_ limit, which is 999)

Here are the errors I am getting when using the first return statement.

```
Got Error: <twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'sqlite3.ProgrammingError'>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python26\lib\threading.py", line 504, in __bootstrap
self.__bootstrap_inner()
File "c:\python26\lib\threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "c:\python26\lib\threading.py", line 484, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
--- <exception caught here> ---
File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\threadpool.py", line 207, i
n _worker
result = context.call(ctx, function, *args, **kwargs)
File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\context.py", line 118, in c
allWithContext
return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\context.py", line 81, in ca
llWithContext
return func(*args,**kw)
File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\enterprise\adbapi.py", line 448, i
n _runInteraction
result = interaction(trans, *args, **kw)
File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\enterprise\adbapi.py", line 462, i
n _runQuery
trans.execute(*args, **kw)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current sta
tement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your question's not very clear.  "assign a value to uuid"?  Do you mean like an `INSERT` or `UPDATE`?  If so, please show that code.  Please include a complete, runnable example of both working and non-working examples (replete with the schema, i.e. all relevant `CREATE TABLE` statements).

Comment: Glyph, I have added the entire program. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [the API documentation for runQuery](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.enterprise.adbapi.ConnectionPool.html#runQuery).  Next, consider the difference between these three function calls:

```
c = a, b
f(a, b)
f((a, b))
f(c)
```

Finally, don't paraphrase error messages.  Always quote them verbatim.  Copy/paste whenever possible; make a note when you've manually transcribed them.

Comment: Thanks, Jean-Paul. Will take a look.

Comment: Jean-Paul, I modified the sql statement to get one line at a time form the DB but have found another problem, which is rather odd. I have shown all details in the edit section in the original post. I checked all API documents but can find no reason for this. Any ideas?

Comment: It's a mystery to me how your new SELECT statement ever works.  The second argument to runQuery must be a tuple, not an integer.  runQuery(foo, (count,)) is correct.  runQuery(foo, count) is wrong.  It shouldn't matter whether count equals 10 or anything else.

Comment: That works. However I found the following example in the API documents   -def getAge(user):
    return dbpool.runQuery("SELECT age FROM users WHERE name = ?", user)--so why does this work even though its not a tuple? link is:(http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/rdbms.htm) --